# How to access jdbc properties file (for Spring Security configuration) which is outside WEB-INF folder?

Tags: java, tomcat, configuration, spring-security

How can we access jdbc properties in Spring Security configuration which are outside WEB-INF folder of the webapp? My project hierarchy is like below:

```
tomcat
  webapps
    appName
       Configuration
         jdbc.properties
         other configuration files too are here
      WebPages
         all the jsps/htmls here
      WEB-INF
         web.xml
         spring-security.xml
      classes/
      lib/
      tlds/
```

Inside spring-security.xml I am trying to refer jdbc.properties and everytime I get file not found exception,

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="file:${catalina.home}/webapps/appName/configuration/jdbc.properties"/>

        <property name="location" value="file:${catalina.base}/webapps/appName/configuration/jdbc.properties"/>

<property name="location" value="/configuration/jdbc.properties"/>

<property name="location" value="file:/configuration/jdbc.properties"/>

<property name="location" value="classpath:/configuration/jdbc.properties"/>

<property name="location" value="classpath:/configuration/jdbc.properties"/>

</bean>
```

{catalina.home} and {catalina.base} work but only till the server restart or application redeploy happens. Almost all the answers here on SO or on internet point to solution where `jdbc.properties` file is placed in classpath (i.e inside classes folder) however I can't do that in my project due to internal reasons.

Comment: Put them in the CLASSPATH, of course.  They belong in WEB-INF/classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you move your properties file to **src/main/resources**, assuming your project is managed by maven, then you could retrieve it by doing

```
Properties prop = new Properties();

try {
    // load a properties file
    prop.load(YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/jdbc.properties")); // note the leading /

    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("password"));

} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

where YourClass is whatever class this code is in.

Maven places the class files of your compiled classes and all resources in src/main/resources in **WEB-INF/classes** where only your application can access them.

If you put the file in **src/main/resources/someFolder**, you'll need to access it from

prop.load(YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/someFolder/jdbcProperties"));
The path you provide to the above method is relative to the package of the class you are in, unless you specify a leading forward-slash, in which case it will be relative to the root of the classpath, ie classes folder.

Comment: property files are not inside src (they are parallel to it) and I am not using Maven. Please see the project structure in question.